# How do I :Ggrep ignoring case for a particular search?

Tags: vim, case-insensitive, vim-fugitive

Is there a way to do a one-off search using `:Ggrep` ignoring case?
That is, what I'd do with `git grep -i search_term` in the shell?

The standard `:vimgrep` suggest embedding the `\c` modifier into the search pattern but `:Ggrep /\csearch_term/` did not appear to work at all.

So, the question: is there a way to make `:Ggrep` ignore case for a particular search action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-i`/`--ignore-case` flag for `:Ggrep`:

```
:Ggrep -i 'pattern'
```